# How can I detect unchecked checkbox with php?

Tags: php, checkbox

There are 3(I do not know how many would be it changeable. 3 only example) checkboxes in my form and I want to detect unchecked checkboxes with php when it post. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Gumbo is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542900/how-can-i-detect-unchecked-checkbox-with-php#13542924). There is a work around however, and that is the following:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="checkbox" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In other words: have a hidden field with the same name as the checkbox and a value that represents the unchecked state, `0` for instance. It is, however, important to have the hidden field *precede* the checkbox in the form. Otherwise the hidden field's value will override the checkbox value when posted to the backend, if the checkbox was checked.

Another way to keep track of this is to have a list of possible checkboxes in the back-end (and even populate the form in the back-end with that list, for instance). Something like the following should give you an idea:

```
<?php

$checkboxes = array(
    array( 'label' => 'checkbox 1 label', 'unchecked' => '0', 'checked' => '1' ),
    array( 'label' => 'checkbox 2 label', 'unchecked' => '0', 'checked' => '1' ),
    array( 'label' => 'checkbox 3 label', 'unchecked' => '0', 'checked' => '1' )
);

if( strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] ) == 'post' )
{
    foreach( $checkboxes as $key => $checkbox )
    {
        if( isset( $_POST[ 'checkbox' ][ $key ] ) && $_POST[ 'checkbox' ][ $key ] == $checkbox[ 'checked' ] )
        {
            echo $checkbox[ 'label' ] . ' is checked, so we use value: ' . $checkbox[ 'checked' ] . '<br>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo $checkbox[ 'label' ] . ' is not checked, so we use value: ' . $checkbox[ 'unchecked' ] . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <?php foreach( $checkboxes as $key => $checkbox ): ?>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[<?php echo $key; ?>]" value="<?php echo $checkbox[ 'checked' ]; ?>"><?php echo $checkbox[ 'label' ]; ?></label><br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

... check one or two checkboxes, then click the submit button and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you, Well Is there no way to detect it?

Comment: Not without my example, or without keeping track of the checkboxes in the back-end. My example submits the hidden value of `0` for `$_POST['checkbox']` if the checkbox is unchecked, otherwise it submits `1`.

Comment: @fireeyedboy Actually, both `checkbox=0` and `checkbox=1` will be submitted but `$_POST` will only reflect the last.

Comment: @Gumbo I take it you mean when the checkbox is checked? In that case, you are right indeed.

Comment: @prestack I've added an example for you of how you could keep track of the checkboxes in the back-end and determine their state when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 12):

[Only checked checkboxes are submitted.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) So any checkbox that is not submitted is unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this check entirely in PHP with the following function:

```
function cbToBool($cb = true) {
    if (isset($cb)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

using it like this

```
$_POST["blocked"] = cbToBool($_POST["blocked"]);
```